# JavaScript initializing/appending/updating array of arrays

Tags: javascript, list, multidimensional-array, push

I'm new to javascript and have been researching for quite a while now, but can't figure out this syntax. When I try to push an array into another array, it pushes the elements individually instead of creating an array of arrays like I want.

What I'm trying to do:

`lastTimes` as array of arrays:

```
lastTimes = [[1, 12435235], [2,443531923], [3,4925951]]
```

if: `IDandTime = [5, 5959393]`

append `IDandTime` to `lastTimes` as an array:

```
lastTimes = [[1, 12435235], [2,443531923], [3,4925951], [5, 5959393]]
```

or if ID (`IDandTime[0]`) already exists, update that array's time within `lastTimes`:

if `IDandTime = [1, 50305240]`
update ID 1's time to 50305240:

```
lastTimes = [[1, 50305240], [2,443531923], [3,4925951], [5, 5959393]]
```

Would anyone mind helping me out here please? I've tried many combinations of syntaxes and can't get it right, nor have I been successful in figuring out the proper search term to find a preexisting answer. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

code:

```
var lastTimes = [];
var IDandTime = [1, 5935935];
lastTimes.push(IDandTime);
```

result:

```
lastTimes = [1, 5935935]
```

the result I want:

```
lastTimes = [[1, 5935935]]
```

**EDIT2:**

Ok here is the full function I am working with. I have a node.js server with an XBee serial module, and several Arduino temperature sensors with XBee serial modules. I have a handshake mechanism working, but I'm trying to achieve error checking for when nodes drop out, so their stale data is no longer used. I feel like this is really just a problem with basic 2D array syntax though.

```
// Open a new serial port connection 
sp.on("open", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
    }
    console.log('open');


    var nodeCount = 0;
    var nodes = []; // get rid of after debugging
    var lastTimes = [];
    lastTimes[0] = [0,0]; // initalize as 2D array for later


    //  Grab data from buffer
    sp.on('data', function(data) {
        // Initialize time Object
        var time = new Date();
        // Split incoming data by newline
        var buffer0 = data.split('\n');

        // New node handshake initiation received
        if (buffer0 == "BROADCASTING") {
            nodeCount++;
            var sendID = nodeCount.toString();
            sp.write(sendID);
            console.log("Broadcast received. Sending identifier #" + sendID);
            nodes.push(nodeCount);
        }

        // Preconnected node data received
        if ((buffer0 != "BROADCASTING") && (nodeCount > 0)) {
            var receiveTime = time.getTime();
            // [ID, Temp] touple
            var nodeData = buffer0[0].split(" ");
            console.log("NodeID: " + nodeData[0] + "    Temp(F): " + nodeData[1]);          
            // [ID, Time] touple
            var IDandTime = [];
            IDandTime.push(nodeData[0]);
            IDandTime.push(time.getTime());
            console.log("IDandTime: " + IDandTime);

            // Check for preexisting node ID
            var oldNode = 0; 
            var nodeIndex = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < lastTimes.length; i++) {
                if (lastTimes[i][0] == IDandTime[0]) {
                    oldNode = 1;
                    nodeIndex = i;
                }
            }
            // If new node, add new node data to lastTimes (list of [ID, Time] touples)
            if (oldNode == 0) {
                lastTimes[lastTimes.length] = IDandTime;
                console.log("lastTimes: " + lastTimes);
            }
            // If preexisting node, update preexisting node time
            else if (oldNode == 1) {
                lastTimes[i][1] = IDandTime[1];
            }




        }



    });
});
```

error from my last attempt at finding the proper syntax:

```
                lastTimes[i][1] = IDandTime[1];
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
```

Comment: If you give us the code you're using to put an array in an array, then we might be able to tell you why it's not doing what you want.

Comment: An ES6 [MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) be of use here. Even if just a reference as how to do it.

Comment: I didn't post the code because it has so much irrelevant parts mixed in (using node.js as a server for wireless modules) that I thought it'd obfuscate the actual issue, which I think I made clear in my post. For the most part I've tried many combinations of `IDandTime = [1, 59395]` then `lastTimes.push(IDandTime)`, which instead of resulting in `lastTimes = [[1,59395]]`, results in `lastTimes = [1, 59395]`

Comment: Without seeing your code we won't know the issue.

Comment: `it has so much irrelevant parts mixed in` we don't need the irrelevant parts, just the relevant - how are you trying to push an array into another array.

Comment: made an edit to make things more clear

Comment: I think it was quite clear what you want to achieve, but we are unable to appreciate the problem that you have with your code as you haven't posted any.

Comment: just added all the information I could

Comment: Adding `break;` after `nodeIndex = i;` should solve your issue in your code. Because you continue to loop even after finding the item, therefore `i` becomes `lastTimes.length` and hence `lastTimes[i]` is `undefined`. Though there are better ways to code what you have.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I guess I really did need to post all the code. I'm open to suggestions for a cleaner way of going about this.

Comment: Using ES5 or ES6 are cleaner,  the answer posted by @NenadVracar is a good example. But if you read about `Map` then you will see that you could equally use a Javascript Object Literal, like suggested by @ZoltanTamasi As you are using a recent version of Node, I would start using ES6 if I were you. Also take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code that is working, but you are looking for improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if `data` is string, then calling `data.split('\n')` returns Array (see. [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)), so each of your compares `if (buffer0 == "BROADCASTING")` are evaluated to `false`. You probably want to compare first line of the data, and first line is in `buffer0[0]`, so write the conditions `if (buffer0[0] == ... )`.

Then you have error in code

```
// If preexisting node, update preexisting node time
else if (oldNode == 1) {
    lastTimes[i][1] = IDandTime[1];
}
```

where you are using variable `i` from loop, but because the loop is not terminated with `break` keyword, the loop is always going through the whole array and after the loop is finished, variable `i` is setted to `lastTimes.length`, which points  to non existing index in the array.

I would write the loop like this:

```
var IDandTime = [];
var nodeIndex = nodeData[0];
IDandTime.push(nodeIndex);
IDandTime.push(time.getTime());

var foundAtIndex;
for (var i = 0, l = lastTimes.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (lastTimes[i][0] === nodeIndex) {
        foundAtIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (typeof foundAtIndex === 'undefined') {
     lastTimes.push(IDandTime);
} else {
    lastTimes[foundAtIndex] = IDandTime;
}
```

Comment: does it default to the `[0]` index? because it seems to be working anyway, even though I realize that that does look like an issue. For the 2nd issue, thanks also. I meant to use `nodeIndex = i` then `lastTimes[nodeIndex][1]` so that I didn't need to `break`, but I guess either would work.

Comment: It is another issue that you have. If you also look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport you will see an option to perform this split for you, `parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\n')`. But your code would still have the mentioned problem. The `break` is necessary to stop the loop, as you don't need to keep looking once you find what you want. Even if you use another variable to store `i`.

Comment: @Jake, the arrays in JS does not defaults to first element, and `String.prototype.split()` always returns an Array and Array do not equals to String (although string and array has much in common), so if the `data` parameter really is an string (which obviously is), then `buffer0 == "BROADCASTING"` could possibly never evaluate to true.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `findIndex` to check if first number is in some of elements in array and change that element in original array or push new element to array.

```js
var lastTimes = [[1, 12435235], [2,443531923], [3,4925951]];

function update(val) {
  var i = lastTimes.findIndex(function(e) {
    return e[0] == val[0];
  });

  if (i != -1) {
    lastTimes[i][1] = val[1];
  } else {
    lastTimes.push(val);
  }
}


update([1, 50305240])
console.log(lastTimes)
```

Comment: Note: `Array#findIndex` is an ES6 method, but fully shimmable. Otherwise this is ES3. An example I also had waiting, but I wanted the OP to show their problem first. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pure object (without prototype) instead of an array, like this:

```
var lastTimes = Object.create(null);
```

And instead of pushing a tuple, you could just set the properties of this object. This way you don't have to handle updating or appending manually, everything just work automatically, like this:

```
var receiveTime = time.getTime();
// [ID, Temp] touple
var nodeData = buffer0[0].split(" ");
console.log("NodeID: " + nodeData[0] + "    Temp(F): " + nodeData[1]);          
// [ID, Time] touple
var IDandTime = [];
IDandTime.push(nodeData[0]);
IDandTime.push(time.getTime());
console.log("IDandTime: " + IDandTime);

lastTimes[nodeData[0]] = time.getTime();
```

To iterate over the values:

```
Object.keys(lastTimes).forEach(id => {
    var value = lastTimes[id];
});
```

And to lookup a value by id is just:

```
var value = lastTimes[id];
```

Comment: `Object.create(null);` could be simplified to **`{}`**. `Object.create()` does only makes sense, if you want to create object with some prototype. If you want object with `prototype = null`, then `{}` makes exactly that object.

Comment: This is not true. {} will create an object with the Object as constructor function and the resulting object will 'inherit' functions like 'hasOwnProperty'. 
Try it out:
console.log({}.hasOwnProperty)
console.log(Object.create(null).hasOwnProperty)

Comment: you are right. Both methods produce new `object` without `prototype`, but output of `Object.create(null)` has also `constructor === undefined`, which is interesting and I did not knew that. But it has very few consequences, (even `for ... in` loop works the same way -- you do not have to use `hasOwnProperty()`), so I see no incentive to use more verbose and less familiar `Object.create(null)`, or am I wrong?

Comment: {} will create an object which actually has a prototype: Object.prototype. Check this: console.log(({}).__proto__ === Object.prototype). 
Yes it's true it has very few consequences. Anytime you lookup a property on an object, JS will start to traverse the prototype chain. It's a very subtle difference to traverse 1 prototype vs 0 prototype, I guess the difference is so little that it wont even show up in performance tests.

Comment: Anyways I like to differentiate between {} and Object.create(null), because the difference in the intention is clearly visible from the code. I prefer using {} when I want an object and Object.create(null) when what I want is not really an object but I only want to use the hashmap-like behaviour of the object, like in the above scenario.

Comment: damn, I though I understand prototypes clearly, but I did not. `{}` really has a `prototypes` and that prototypes is `Object`. I came up with my comment from piece of knowledge, that `Object`, as last element in prototypical inheritance, has prototype `null`, but I did not take into consideration, that `{}` is already a descendant of `Object`. Than you for that update.